# how to remove scroll bar in jpeg image

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, codeigniter

I have written some code to convert html in a bootstrap modal to image in jpeg format.

It is working fine but in the image it is showing some scroll bar(s). In this code I didn't include any scrollbar.

How to resolve this problem. can any one please help me. [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO9iv.jpg) here I have included one image, I am getting scrollbar like this when I click on the download button.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#jpgfrmt", function() {
  domtoimage.toJpeg(document.getElementById('download'), {
      quality: 0.95
    })
    .then(function(dataUrl) {
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = 'astDetails.jpeg';
      link.href = dataUrl;
      link.click();
    });
});
```

```css
#download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: auto;
  height: auto
}

#buttons {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline;
}

#jpgfrmt {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" class="content">
  <div id="buttons">
    <div class="action_btn">
      <a href="javascript:;" id="jpgfrmt" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning m-b-10">
        <i class="fa fa-download m-r-5"></i> Download
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="download">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td style="border:none;">
              <table class="table">
                <tr>
                  <td class="field highlight" width="25%" style="border:none;">Name:</td>
                  <td width="75%" style="border:none;">
                    Name
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="field" width="25%" style="border:none;">Description:</td>
                  <td width="75%" style="border:none;">
                    Description
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="field" width="25%" style="border:none;">Serial No:</td>
                  <td width="75%" style="border:none;">
                    Serial Number
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may not fix your issue, but you should fix this: `<div id="#buttons">` There should be no `#`: `<div id="buttons">`

Comment: I've converted the code you provided to a working snippet (including removing the server-side code (php) and fixing the above typo which doesn't *seem* to be related).  It creates a jpg without scroll bars.  Can you update the snippet to *demonstrate* the issue?  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: Hi sir. Thanks for your reply. This issue is coming because of design, if i put the id download in tbody it is coming properly, if i put somewhere outside of tbody it shows scroll.